# PayPal iOS MPL Error 559044 "This receiver accepts PayPal payments only through their website"

Tags: ios, paypal

I have integrated the PayPal MPL library for iOS. After successfully testing via the sandbox, I submitted the app to PayPal and got my live app ID back.

I plugged in the live app ID, and set the MPL framework to use ENV_LIVE.

Now, when checking out via PayPal, I get the following warning logged out in the console:

```
severity: Warning
category: Request
errorId: 559044
message: This receiver accepts PayPal payments only through their website
```

And when performing the payment, I get the error:

```
"Payment declined. The recipient has chosen to block this payment".
```

How do I update the merchant account to accept payments from mobile devices? I can't find this anywhere.

If it helps, I am testing this on the device itself (but connected the to console). The merchant account is UK based, and the currency used is GBP on both the merchant account, and app.

Comment: @ a1phanumeric

Hey bro..Sorry for commenting here for an unrelated question,I have no other way to contact you

Have got any solution for FGallery auto rotation in iOS6,if you have please help me..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700987/issue-in-fgallery-while-using-with-ios6

Comment: Huh? How did you make that link to me? I have it working in my apps - I'll dig out the code on my lunch break :)

Comment: I have seen a discussion and your answer in Git,but could not understand how to work that out

Answer (score 0):

Are you mixing sandbox and live accounts? That was the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates the seller account is set up to block the payment.

Googling your error # gives a better how-to for these settings than I could write so this is block-copied:

To view and change your settings for blocked payments, please follow these steps:

1. Log in to your PayPal account and navigate to: My account > Profile > My selling tools [note: PayPal has updated pages a lot recently; you may have to poke around depending upon which version of the interface you have]
2. Then, on the the My selling tools page, to the right of the Block payments item, please click the Update link.
3. In the page that loads, please make sure that your account is:

NOT set to "Block Payments for the items not sold on eBay from U.S. users who do not provide a confirmed address" 
NOT set to block payments from users who "Initiate payments from the Pay Anyone subtab of the Send Money tab" 
NOT set to block payments in a currency you do not hold 
NOT set to block payments from Student accounts (optional) 
DON'T FORGET to save your changes before you leave the page

(end block-copy). I will add one more possibility that is MPL-specific: some features in the MPL require authorization from PayPal (for security reasons). Most of these are at the app level (which you should have since you went through the application process) but it is possible that your receiving (seller) account lacks some key vetting/endorsement for MPL and PayPal may have reused this error code for that. If there are no blocks on that prefs page, then ping PayPal to ask whether the receiver needs vetting to access the features you are using.